# Spontaneous "connection refused" error using Selenium in R

Tags: r, connection, port, rselenium

I have written several different scripts that utilize the RSelenium package's automated web browsing. However, on occasion, the window will spontaneously close while in the middle of running, and I will get this error :

```
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4567: Connection refused
```

When this happens, the web browser will close which forces me to restart the script. Then, once restarted, the script will work fine. I run these scripts often (maybe a dozen times a day, ignoring re-runs due to the error), and have had this error happen at different stages of the scripts. The error seems to happen randomly. Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing this?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: My solution was to just rewrite everything in Javascript. So far there has been no more spontaneous failures, and I have found that Selenium with Javascript is much more well documented than with R (which came in handy because I am a novice with Javascript).